# mongodb connect fail in osx

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos, shell

I'm newer to mongode, I use shell to start mongodb service but failed and get following error. What should I do?

**mongod log**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VTSe.png)

**mongo log**

`MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-05-07T07:59:40.141+1000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-05-07T07:59:40.142+1000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed`

Comment: Did you start the daemon first with mongod?

Comment: I have already start mongod

Comment: So in one terminal window, after starting `mongod`, you should see this:

    `2017-05-06T15:18:51.840-0700 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017`

Do you see that? If not is there something about /data/db?

Comment: no, this is my log

Comment: 2017-05-07T08:24:01.125+1000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1148 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=192-168-1-8.tpgi.com.au

Comment: Yeah, that's the first line. What's the last line of that log?

Comment: 2017-05-07T08:41:38.547+1000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-05-07T08:41:38.547+1000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-05-07T08:41:38.547+1000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100

Comment: Please modify your question with the full `mongod` log.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Open terminal, and at the prompt type:

```
sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db
```

Exactly as written. This will give you write access to the /data/db directory which is what Mongo is complaining about. It should prompt you for your password. Once it does enter it and hit enter. After that, kill mongod, if running, and restart.

Comment: You sir are awesome! This was just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the MongoDB server (`mongod`) is listening on the right interface.

Listening on `127.0.0.1` (loopback interface) will only work locally. If you want to handle remote requests you will have to listen on a network interface that can be accessed remotely. Listening on `0.0.0.0` will listen on all network interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Please check whether you have C:\data\db. If you dont have it create it manually.

Step 2: in command line go to directory of mongodb such as *c:\Program files\Mongodb\server\3.4\bin* and type ***mongod**

Step 3: type Mongo

Hopefully its gonna work out for you.